# TinyMCE remove white spaces at the end of text REACT

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

[image]

when I add a whitespace at the end of the text, I got this as a result

```
<p>TEXT&nbsp;</p>
```

How can I wether getting white spaces at the end eliminate or just getting the actual white space
example:

```
<p>TEXT </p>
```

Comment: What problem do you have with the current one?

Comment: I just need it wether without spaces or with the actual space. With the current one I cant handle make search by field name having "&nbsp"

Comment: What get query do you mean?

Comment: I just cant use it like that

Comment: TinyMCE should have an API to get the content text.